# How do I use mouseClicked() with an irregular object

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

So far, my mouseClicked() method uses getX() and getY(). to see if the user clicks on a picture of the lungs. However, by using x and y, the "zone" of success is a box, rather than the shape of a lung. As a result, clicking to the right or left of the lung also generates a successful click in my mouseClicked method. Is there a way where I can change it so that only clicks on the lung will generate a successful event?

Thanks in advance.

[Clicking to the top left and bottom right of the left lung generates a successful event when it shouldn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEKIN.jpg)

Comment: You need to define a "shape" (ie `Polygon`) which represents the clickable area - The Graphics 2D API provides a number of helpful classes to do this.  From this you can then use said `Shape` to perform hit testing

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to make use of the [Graphics 2D shapes API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html).

This allows you to create an arbitrary shape (polygon) and make use of it's various collision detection functionality to determine if the mouse has moved into or out of it

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Shape> paths;
        private Shape filled;

        public TestPane() {
            double radius = 50;
            double orginX = 100;
            double orginY = 100;
            int dif = (int) (360 / 12d);
            paths = new ArrayList<>(25);

            for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += dif) {
                double angle = Math.toRadians(i);
                double centerX = radius * Math.cos(angle) + orginX;
                double centerY = radius * Math.sin(angle) + orginY;

                Path2D path = new Path2D.Double();
                path.moveTo(radius * Math.cos(angle + Math.toRadians(60)) + centerX, radius * Math.sin(angle + Math.toRadians(60)) + centerY);
                path.lineTo((radius * Math.cos(angle - Math.toRadians(60)) + centerX), (radius * Math.sin(angle - Math.toRadians(60)) + centerY));
                path.lineTo(orginX, orginY);
                paths.add(path);
            }

            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                    filled = null;
                    for (Shape path : paths) {
                        if (path.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                            filled = path;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (Shape shape : paths) {
                if (shape == filled) {
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    g2.fill(shape);
                }
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.draw(shape);
            }
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```